# Switch Activity on Splash Screen Interruption by touching any part of screen?

Tags: android

I wish to interrupt splash screen within 5 seconds and go to next activity.

```
 new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000)
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

        @Override
        public void onFinish() 
        {
            Intent I = new Intent(Home.this, Welcome1.class);
            startActivity(I);
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: if you wish to interrupt it, why did you programma it in the first place?

Comment: That's NOT THE ANSWER. Its about choice.Few users have patience ,few don't.

Comment: fair enough. Do you have a `cancel` button there ?

Comment: By the way I am Black Belt Too :)

Comment: you will need a button. Something that allows the user to skip the waiting time

Comment: Actually I wish to touch any part of screen to  go to next activty.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        ....
        splashDelaey();
   }


     void splashDelaey(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               Intent I = new Intent(Home.this, Welcome1.class);
               I.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(I); 
            }
        },5000);
    }
```

Comment: I did not work.Initially i got error at Handler.when i resolved it,it showed same result.

Answer (score 0):

try this.Hope it helps

```
Thread splashTread; //Declare this class level variable     

  splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(900);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            } finally {

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(Home.this,Welcome1.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        }
    };

    splashTread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This work well

```
  Thread background = new Thread() {
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
                        sleep(3000);
                        // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Welcome1.class);
                        startSpecificActivity(i);
                        //Remove activity
                        finish();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            // start thread
            background.start();
```

Comment: Did not work.I wish to touch any part of screen to switch to next activity within 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

in your Activity, retrive the root view of your layout using `findViewById`, and register a ClickListener on it. On the same object you can post a `Runnable` with `postDelayed`. If you press on the screen, assuming that your layout takes the whole screen, `onClick` is called. There you can remove the runnable from the View's handler and start the new `Activity`. E.g.

```
private View mRootView;
private Runnable mRunnable;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    mRootView = findViewById(R.id.rootview);
    mRootView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Welcome1.class);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(intent);
           mRootView.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        }
    });

    mRootView.postDelayed(mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Intent I = new Intent(Home.this, Welcome1.class);
           I.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
          startActivity(I); 
        }
    },5000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answer.All i did is added this code

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

```
    boolean defaultResult = super.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Welcome1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return defaultResult;
```